# responsive size textarea flickers on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, textarea, responsive

So, I have this responsive-height `textarea` inside a React component and on desktop, it works fine, but on mobile, for some reason, if the textarea grows beyond the window height and I press `space` or any word from the keyboard-autosuggest, the scroll goes to the top of the textarea.

this is the code I'm running:

```js
 const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
  const handleTextAreaChange = (event) => {
    const textarea = event.target
    textarea.style.height = 'auto' // Reset height to auto
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 'px' // Set the height to match the content
    setDescription(event.target.value)
  }

 <Form.Group
                    as={Col}
                    className="mb-3"
                    controlId="blog-description"
                  >
                    <Form.Control
                      className="description-input"
                      style={descriptionFont}
                      //value={description}
                      as="textarea"
                      // Adjust the number of rows as needed
                      placeholder={placeholder}
                      onChange={(event) => handleTextAreaChange(event)}
                      //onKeyDown={(event) => delayedResize(event)}
                      //autoFocus
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
```

**css:**

```css
.blog-form textarea {
  width: 100%;

  resize: none; 
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I saw some similar questions, but I was curious why this only happens on mobile? On desktop it all works fine

Answer (score 0):

If there is anyone that gets this behaviour and couldn't find a solution, here is what worked for me:

```js
  const handleTextAreaChange = (event) => {
    const textarea = event.target
    const lineHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(textarea).lineHeight, 10)
    const minVisibleLines = 4 

    const content = textarea.value
    const lines = content.split('\n')

    
    const numberOfLines = lines.length

    
    const fixedHeight = Math.max(
      lineHeight * minVisibleLines,
      lineHeight * numberOfLines,
    )
    textarea.style.height = fixedHeight + 'px'
    setDescription(event.target.value)
  }
```

and setting the overflow of the textarea to hidden:

```css
.blog-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none; 
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

we calculate the number of lines (including empty lines, splitting new lines) then set a height for the textarea based on the number of lines. It seems that the flickery behaviour disappeared.
I set the overflow on textarea to hidden as I'm using this inside another container (`.blog-form`) that has a fixed `height` and I set the `overflow-y: scroll` on that one and it works like a charm